# Calling super() with arguments set in sub-class __init__()?

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

So I have a class (let's call it `ParamClass`) which requires a parameter for initialization, and that parameter is something that should be available to the user to configure via some option-setting interface.

`ParamClass` knows nothing about the configuration interface or how to read them.  So I made another class, called `Configurator`, which does all of that.  When a class inherits from `Configurator` and tells it what configuration keys to read, `Configurator`'s `__init__()` method will read those keys and assign their values to the correct attributes in `self`.

The problem I run into, however, is that when I try to pass arguments to super(), including the parameters to be read by `Configurator`, those parameters have no value yet.  But they are passed as constants in the argument list to the `super()`.  Example shown below.  `MyClass.__init__()` can't even get started because `self.server_param` doesn't exist yet.

```
class ParamClass:
    """Just some class that needs a parameter for init"""
    def __init__(self, param1, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.value = param1


class Configurator:
    """Reads parameters from a configuration source and sets appropriate class 
       variables.
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.server_param = 2


class MyClass(Configurator, ParamClass):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(param1=self.server_param, **kwargs)  
            # <-- Gives AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'server_param'

MyClass()
```

The only way I can get this to work is to break MRO in `Configurator.init()` and force the order of initilization.  This is bad for obvious reason - I plan to use `Configurator` throughout my code and can't break MRO with it.

```
class ParamClass:
    """Just some class that needs a parameter for init"""
    def __init__(self, param1, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.value = param1


class Configurator:
    """Reads parameters from a configuration source and sets appropriate class 
       variables.
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        # super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.server_param = 2


class MyClass(Configurator, ParamClass):
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs) -> None:
        Configurator.__init__(self, **kwargs)  
            # <-- After this call, self.server_param is defined.
        ParamClass.__init__(self, param1=self.server_param, **kwargs)


MyClass()
```

How do I accomplish configuration of parameters in while user `super`?  How do I do this in a generalized way that doesn't require `Configurator` to know little details about `ParamClass`?

Note: In my particular case, I don't "own" the `ParamClass()` code.  It is library code that I'm using.

Comment: Seem like this might be an opportunity to prefer composition over inheritance. Is `MyClass` really a *type* of `Configurator` or does it just *have* a `Configurator`?

Comment: I don't know if it makes sense model-wise, but `ParamClass` could be a subclass of `Configurator`, and then its constructor could do `self.value = server_param` and `MyClass` would just inherit from `ParamClass` and wouldn't pass any additional arguments. - My inkling is to agree with @MarkMeyer though...if wiring up your inheritance tree is this much work, it usually means that your model is wrong, and you should be doing something like favoring composition or delegation over inheritance.

Comment: Seems to me that what `Configurator` does is create instances of `ParamClass`es — so it does need to be a subclass of them (as @Steve points out, as well). This means it could just be a function. You could get fancy and make it a "functor" class that defined a `__call__()` method which would make it possible to subclass _it_ to make other kinds of callable configurator objects (which would all still return instances of a `ParamClass`).